# Pulled out of job interview - they want to talk to me about my reasons

Tags: interviewing, rejection

I applied for a tech job, went through several rounds of interviews and got called to the final round. However, I did not like the job and decided to pull out of the process. Wrote a polite email saying the job is interesting but not a good fit for me at the moment. I thought that will be it and that I won't hear from them anymore.

Next day I get an email from the recruiter saying she would like to talk more. I did not answer immediately because I had a lot on my plate. A week goes by and another interviewer gets back to me saying the same thing in different words.

The reason I pulled out was I wanted to work on a specific project they had and they did not want to commit upfront to having me work on that. This was a huge red flag for me. The other team/project they had was not of particular interest to me and I would definitely not want to work on that.

How do I approach this? Do I tell them why I pulled out?

Comment: @Fattie, What are you afraid of? That they could bamboozle you into taking a position that you do not want to take? Please see my answer below. Because I do not understand your thinking.

Comment: "They" want to talk to you... It seems an important distinction that the _recruiter_ wants to talk more, not the _company_ who was interviewing. If you have no interest in the company, that's a different question than if you are interested in keeping a relationship with this recruiter.

Comment: @sf02 because I am polite. It's business talk. It's like when you get a rejection letter saying they were impressed but went with another candidate. Took my cue from that.

Comment: @spuck the recruiter works for the.company, they have internal recruiters. Maybe should have made that a bit clearer. I want to keep the relationship with the recruiter, yes

Comment: I think you should mention this project to the recruiter who knows he might help you get in that team.

Comment: @Robotron, being that the recruiter is an employee of the company I think you absolutely want to talk with them. If you want to work on project Y but were interviewed for project X, I see only upsides to let them know that.

Comment: You should have followed through with the process, and then if they offered you the position, you tell them you have the condition that you want to work on a specific project. Potentially you could have negotiated this, I feel you pulled out way to soon. You can always decline a job offer if they refuse.

Comment: After asking twice and not getting a positive answer back I felt it is not a place for me. There were some other bits and pieces about that job that I did not like as well.

Answer (score 14):

Please do. Recruiters, interviewers and the tech company are human beings who care about doing their best job. They expended resources on you, but you backed out, which of course happens all the time. The nice-human thing to do is answer their questions. The upside for them is they can better tune their processes, and the upside for you is a recruiter that understands your interests better.

Comment: Giving them an answer might cause one of them to get offended. I expressed my preference clearly to the interviewer and then they started giving me some murky answers that I did not care for. I want to send them off diplomatically and would rather not burn the bridge.

Comment: @Robotron then time to demonstrate your communication skills. Only you understand your context well enough to do so, but perhaps you can: compliment the people, show your appreciation for the other role, respectfully state that it is not what you want at this time.

Comment: @Robotron You say you  do not want to burn the bridge with this company, and that implies that at some point in the future there is a possibility that you would apply to this company again.   If you are not straightforward with this company now and tell them why you are withdrawing from  the process this time, what makes you think you will have any better luck next time and not have the exact same experience  again, wasting your time and theirs?  Better to ask them to  correct their mistake now; even if it doesn't help now then it could help you later.

Comment: @Robotron > Explaining your reason in respectful terms IS diplomatic. Mentioning you already accepted another position would also probably shut down any attempt at them trying to convince you once again. Being diplomatic can not guarantee that anyone won't be "offended", but not giving any reason could also "offend" people, so if you care about that, you should act the most professional way, and I think this answer is the most professional one. If I was dismissed after several rounds of interview, I would certainly appreciate any answer...

Comment: @ertai87 it's a small country and a small market. Nothing to gain by burning bridges. This same recruiter might switch companies in a year or two and I might want to have an in there. Same goes for the interviewer. Their current company is considered top notch local tech company, so I might want to work there in the future as well. Things change.

Comment: @MichaelMcFarlane: sorry, this feel asymmetrical. If you don't get hired they will never ever tell you why not and in many cases they won't even tell you anything at all but just ghost you. Why would different norms of behavior apply to the candidate?

Answer (score 5):

As a general rule - do not volunteer any extraneous information that will not - potentially - lead to your ultimate goal

If you think that disclosing that you are only interested in working on specific project will get you to be hired with written promise that you would

And

that employer will honor this promise made 'under the gun'

Go for it

But, IMHO, you can not be sure to remain on that project.

In any employment contract duties list contains "etc" implication and you can be transferred anywhere your employer need you, with only recourse being resignation

Comment: +1 I have no more interest in this company. They were not willing to provide me with what I asked for on two occasions and that sealed the deal for me. There is nothing for me to gain by providing the reason for pulling out.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that if you had gone to the final stage and gotten an offer, you would have been able to extract a commitment from them. You probably could have stipulated that you would only accept if they guaranteed you would work on your preferred team.

Now that you have withdrawn from the process, they would like to know why (something more than "this position is not a good fit"). You are under no obligation to give a more elaborate answer, but if you do, there is a chance that they may offer you this guarantee. But then again: what happens when the project is over? What if they end up needing you on the other team after, say, 6 months?

Comment: Bait and switch is a thing. It's a question of whether you really want to deal with that and how much the company commits to something. Some companies do plan to "grind and dump" their staff (burn you out, fire you when project is done).

Comment: I have no intent to work there. I found something else and moved on. My main motivation here is to provide an answer. However, some answers might require more involvement on my side, such as providing explanations. If I tell them "here is the reason why I pulled out" someone might get offended. When I asked directly if I will work on this specific project the interviewer started beating around the bush. I don't like that since I have bad experience with such behaviour. When I asked again in the next interview, I got the same beating-around-the-bush approach. That sealed my decision.

Comment: Now, I don't feel comfortable going on a call with them and then berating the interviewer about his behaviour. I am conflict-averse and would rather just have them go away, but still keep the bridges intact.

Comment: @Robotron Then that settles it: no need for you to elaborate. If you want to reply, keep it simple/generic, polite, and honest, like "I found another position, but thank you for your time." Ignore further requests for clarification (e.g. "What made you choose that job over this one?").

Answer (score 1):

> The reason I pulled out was I wanted to work on a specific project
> they had and they **did not want to commit upfront** to having me work on
> that.

Yes, speak to them, but on your terms.

If the person who contacted you doesn't have the power to guarantee you that you'll be able to work on your chosen project, then politely refuse to speak to that person, tell them **why** you're refusing to speak to them, and then politely hang up on them.

By walking away and not looking back, you've unwittingly gained the upper hand in the interaction. This reminds me of the book called [Start with No:](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B082QQF66Q) The Negotiating Tools that the Pros Don't Want You to Know - *Jim Camp* (this is not an endorsement of the book. I'm just mentioning this book, because the very act of saying "no" and walking away can sometimes move mountains).

Now, don't get me wrong. I'm not saying that they've changed their mind, or that they will change their mind. They most likely haven't and most likely won't.

But in the unlikely event that they're willing to budge, it won't cost you anything to find out. Just be firm. Repeat what you want. And treat them just like you would any other pushy telemarketer (but while still keeping your composure).

And in the even more unlikely event that they're willing to change their mind **and** change the contract to guarantee you that particular project, have them change the actual contract, and pay an employment lawyer a few hundred dollars to review it and make sure it's ironclad.

In the meantime, keep on doing what you're doing. Keep on interviewing with other potential employers.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't have to give them an answer at all. If you really want to give them an answer just reiterate that you felt the position would not be a good fit for you. You don't owe them a detailed explanation